# inherited java ArrayList to JSON

Tags: java, json, arraylist

I have a class that overrides ArrayList like:

```
public class SkmeList extends ArrayList<SkmeStatement> {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private int skmeMajor = 0;
  private int skmeMinor = 0;
  private String skmeTable = null;

  public void setTable(String table) {
    System.out.println("Set Table: " + table);
    skmeTable = table;
  }
  public String getTable() {
    return skmeTable;
  }
  public void setMajor(int major) {
    System.out.println("SetMajor: " + major);
    skmeMajor = major;
  }
  public int getMajor() {
    return skmeMajor;
  }
  public void setMinor(int minor) {
    System.out.println("SetMinor: " + minor);
    skmeMinor = minor;
  }
  public int getMinor() {
    return skmeMinor;
  }
}
```

when I attempt to write this class to a file or even a string using jackson I can only see the list contents, I do not see any of class specific attributes like Major or minor in the string/file?  I treat this class just like any other java class.  Is there something that is different with lists in jackson object mapper?

```
public void WriteJson(SkmeList statements) {
    final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try {
        mapper.writeValue(out, statements);

        final byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
        System.out.println(new String(data));
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Foo");
    }
}
```

Comment: You just shouldn't extend ArrayList. Why would you do that?

Comment: Why wouldn't I?  It is a list of elements and the list has parameters that are global to the elements of the list.

Comment: Well, for one thing, JSON arrays can't have parameters. But even without talking about JSON, you shouldn't extend collections. You should use them. Read Josh Bloch's Effective Java for a long explanation.

Comment: [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) is a good read.

Comment: In your specific case, Jackson likely just checks if something is a List/Map/Set and then serializes the contents using the interface. You could write a custom serializer (or whatever Jackson calls it), but really you should just compose existing types.

Comment: So, its better to take a list that has attributes that apply to all elements of the list and turn it into a 'not a list'  so the user of the class has to treat is specially and not as a list?  Or do I re implement all of the list methods and then just pass them on to the list.  This class is a list, not something that uses a list, it just has parameters to the elements, I could have each element of the list carry all of the parameters but that doesn't make sense either.  I guess the real solution is to write a serializer for the list.

Answer (score 0):

A [List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type)) has elements and no further non-element data. If you need more data, you need something that's more than a List.

The user of your class already has to treat it specially if they care about any of the extra fields you've added.

In favoring [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), here's how I'd suggest this class could look like.

```
public class SkmeList {
  private final int major;
  private final int minor;
  private final String table;
  private final List<SkmeStatement> statements;

  // ctor, getters, hashCode, equals and toString omitted
}
```

With more context on what Skme means, we could make the naming even clearer.

To make it easier to reason about, the class should be immutable, to make it safe for use in a `Collection` it should have `hashCode()` and `equals()`, and a `toString()` in case it ever gets printed/logged/debugged around.

If you don't feel like implementing all the omitted methods, consider [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/value/userguide/index.md): you specify the getters and a factory method, the rest is generated for you.

For the user of your class, it's almost the same:

```
SkmeList list = ...
for (SkmeStatement stmt : list) {
   ...
```

now becomes

```
SkmeList list = ...
for (SkmeStatement stmt : list.getStatements()) {
   ...
```